# How to fake an http request on a static site?

Tags: http, static

Let's say I have a github page, which is a static site. From that github page, I need to make http requests (to give examples for a fetch library), but unfortunately there's rate limiting on a lot of public apis.

Currently to get around this, I have a file `foo.js` with `{ foo: 'bar' }` as contents. I can then call `https://alex-cory.github.io/my-repo/foo.js` with a GET request, and it will return the data.

How do we do this for POST, PATCH, PUT, etc...? Remember, this is a static site so we can't use something like [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server)

Comment: A bit confused. Do you mean you are the owner of static site `example.com` and want the visitors to send HTTP requests on that site?

Comment: @shaochuancs updated the question to be more clear. I want the visitors to be able to click a button, and from that site, make http requests to the same site since I can't have a server because it's a static site.

Comment: Do you need a real HTTP POST request? Can web page fake effect do the job?

Answer (score 0):

You must have a backend to handle a request like POST, PUT etc.

Comment: did you not read the part where I said, "this is a static site so we can't use something like json-server." AKA, you can't run a server on a static site.

Comment: But without this it’s impossible not taking into account GET method. Without backend you cannot access data sent to server.